# VS 2017 team services GIT connection can nor spawn askpass

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

by now I worked vith Team Services very good, but from one moment to the othe, I can not access Team Services GIT any more, and get the follwoing error:

Error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
Error encountered while fetching: Git failed with a fatal error.
could not read Username for 'https://myname.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled

Git Gui works like a charm.

I tried de/reinstall Git tools and to repair VS from VS installation tool .

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot, 
br

Comment: For the sake of specifics, please add a tag to your post of what OS/platform you're having this problem on. Guessing that'd be [windows] or [windows-10].

Comment: No ideas? :/Thanks, br

Answer (score 1):

There is an annoying bug on Visual Studio 2017 as detailed here: [issue-949](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/949)

All you need to do is to update the IDE to release 15.5.7. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I got the repo from my colleague, it was working fine, and some how he changed his credentials or something, and stopped working (Fetch/Pull) with same error in visual studio.
What I did is to re add the remotes with my user name:
Visual Studio -> Team Explorer -> Settings - Repository Settings -> 
Double check everything here. Make sure, username, email, origin remotes are correct and working.